# htaccess rewrite url by matching only the first part of the url

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I've been struggling to find a solution to this very simple problem. You would think that this is the classic "please help me I need to redirect this url to newurl" type of thing but, believe me, it isn't that easy.

I have a domain example.com, this example.com has some language variants:

```
example.com/mx
example.com/us
example.com/ca
example.com/cl 
example.com/xx
```

and so on, example
.com is the index to choose between countries and it exists too but has no content.

We recently moved our example.com/mx to a whole new domain (with a different system) example.com.mx so we proceeded to permanently redirect every url there to the its new url in the example.com.mx

While we were at it, we discovered that our multilingual wordpress installation on example.com was duplicating all website's content in the root file, something which shouldn't have happened.

So, we have like

```
example.com/us/folder
example.com/cl/folder
example.com/ca/folder
etc
```

AND

```
example.com/folder which shouldn't exist
```

There are tons of directories that are duplicated there, we already know where to redirect each of these directories but we just can't find the right line of code to do it.

For example, we have set up this htaccess rule to deal with all the /mx/ folder, which works well:

```
RewriteRule ^mx/shop/ https://www.example.com.mx/? [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^mx/home/ https://www.example.com.mx/? [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^mx/page/ https://www.example.com.mx/? [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^mx/tag/ https://www.example.com.mx/? [L,R=301]
```

But when trying to extend this same logic to the "/shop/" directory, it matches the same directory in EVERY country folder, something we obviously don't want.

This is what we tried, described previously:

```
RewriteRule ^/tag/ https://www.example.com.mx/newtagurl? [L,R=301]
```

This obviously also redirects example.com/ca/tag/, because the ^.

So my question is, how to properly redirect to these cases ONLY matching the beginning https://example.com/tag/ string instead of matching every /tag/ case in every country folder?

Thanks!

Comment: `RewriteRule ^/tag/` should not affect anything, when you configure this in .htaccess - because the leading slash has already been stripped off at that point, so any pattern starting with `^/` will never match. `RewriteRule ^tag/` would match any request URL that starts with `tag/`

Comment: _“This obviously also redirects example.com/ca/tag/, because the ^.”_ - no, that is a completey wrong interpretation of what is happening. `^` anchors the pattern at the beginning, so this would only match paths that start with `/tag/` - this _can not_ ever match `/ca/tag/`